# Javascript Sum Fields Error NaN

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

No mather what I write in the input fields I only get NaN even from the page load I get NaN

Any idea why? I need quantity to * by price and give a result, here is the code. I will display the code now

```
    <form action="?F=save-sale" method="post" name="venta">
<table class="table-global">
      <tr>
        <td class="table-global-td-title">Cantidad

         </td>
        <td class="table-global-td-title">Precio venta</td>
        <td class="table-global-td-title">Vendedor</td>
        <td class="table-global-td-title">Documento</td>

        <td class="table-global-td-title">M&eacute;todo de pago</td>
        <td class="table-global-td-title">Suma total</td>
        <td class="table-global-td-title"></td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="table-global-td-subtitle"><input type="number" class="input-global-100" name="cantidad" id="cantidad">          </td>
          <td class="table-global-td-subtitle"><input type="number" class="input-global-100" name="venta" id="venta" value="0"></td>
           <td class="table-global-td-subtitle"> 
           <select style="text-transform:capitalize" class="select-global-120" name="vendedor" id="vendedor">

  <option value="" selected>Seleccionar</option>
  <option value="001">001</option>

</select>          </td>
        <td class="table-global-td-subtitle"> <select class="select-global-132" name="comprobante" id="comprobante">


          <option value="Boleta" selected>Boleta</option>        
          <option value="Factura">Factura</option>


          </select>        </td>
        <td class="table-global-td-subtitle"><select class="select-global-120" name="metodo" id="metodo" >
          <option value="Transferencia">Transferencia</option>

          <option value="Efectivo" selected>Efectivo</option>
          <option value="Cheque">Cheque</option>
          <option value="Transbank">Transbank</option>



        </select></td>
        <td class="table-global-td-subtitle">

          <input type="text" class="input-global-total-100" name="ventatotal" id="ventatotal" readonly value="0" />        </td>
        <td class="table-global-td-subtitle">
        <input class="submit-global-120" type="submit" value="Realizar la venta" /></td>
      </tr>
      </table>

<script>
var aacosto    = document.getElementsByName('costo')[0];
var aacostototal = document.getElementsByName('costototal')[0];
var aaventa     = document.getElementsByName('venta')[0];
var aaventatotal    = document.getElementsByName('ventatotal')[0];
var aacantidad   = document.getElementsByName('cantidad')[0];
var aaganancia   = document.getElementsByName('ganancia')[0];
var aagananciatotal   = document.getElementsByName('gananciatotal')[0];

function updateInput() {
aaventatotal.value = parseFloat(aaventa.value) * parseFloat(aacantidad.value);

}

aaventa.addEventListener('keyup', updateInput);
aaventatotal.addEventListener('change', updateInput);
aacantidad.addEventListener('keyup', updateInput);
updateInput();
</script>
</form>
```

Here is a Fiddle so you guys can see it working

https://fiddle.jshell.net/v6spxoqv/10/

Comment: Is your script at the bottom of the `<body>` element? If not, either move it there, or put all your `var` statements _inside the function_.

Comment: No in the middle of the code inside the HTML form

Comment: But not under the input fields? Then the HTML elements aren’t loaded yet. Just put the script _under_ the HTML form with the inputs.

Comment: Could you show us the HTML of the form? What do `console.log(aaventa)`,  `console.log(aaventa.value)`, `console.log(aacantidad)` and  `console.log(aacantidad.value)` reveal in the console?

Comment: I inserted the entire code now

Comment: fiddle https://fiddle.jshell.net/v6spxoqv/9/

Answer (score 2):

Just have this condition `if (aaventa.value && aacantidad.value)` before calculating the product. It makes sure that the values are not *empty*. Everything else is fine.

```js
var aaventa = document.getElementsByName('venta')[0];
var aaventatotal = document.getElementsByName('ventatotal')[0];
var aacantidad = document.getElementsByName('cantidad')[0];

function updateInput() {
  if (aaventa.value && aacantidad.value)
    aaventatotal.value = parseFloat(aaventa.value) * parseFloat(aacantidad.value);
  else
    aaventatotal.value = 0;

}

aaventa.addEventListener('keyup', updateInput);
aaventatotal.addEventListener('change', updateInput);
aacantidad.addEventListener('keyup', updateInput);
updateInput();
```

```html
<input name="venta">
<input name="cantidad">
<input name="ventatotal">
```

Comment: @Xufox If the element is *not* in the dom then `element.value` would throw an error.

Comment: @Xufox i don't get it, if you will do `parseFloat("")*parseFloat("")` you will for sure get `NaN`

Comment: @Locatarios i don't think the issue is with the inputs, you just need to put a check as i mentioned above.

Comment: @Locatarios can you please remove PHP from your code and insert JS in javascript block of jsfiddle. It will bring both you and us more clarity of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="venta">
<input id="cantidad">
<input id="ventatotal">
```

Using jQuery

```
$('#venta').change(function(){ updateInput() ;});
$('#cantidad').change(function(){ updateInput() ;});
$('#ventatotal').change(function(){ updateInput() ;});
```